# MVC: Can I use ModelState inside class out of controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Can I do this inside one class?

```
    ...
    using System.Web.Mvc;
    ...

    public static class aaa 
    {

      public static test() {

         if (something) ModelState.AddModelError("", "test");
      }

    }
```

inside controller call:

...

```
public class MyControler {

     public void Index() {
          ....
          aaa.test();
          ....
     }

}
```

Is it possible? I want to control the code inside a classes in another part of the controller.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can pass your model state around like this:

```
public static void test(ModelStateDictionary ModelState)
{
    if (something) ModelState.AddModelError("", "test");
}
```

And call from inside your controller:

```
aaa.test(ModelState);
```

Comment: yes but shoud be out the dictionary or ref, and the compiler doesnt allow it, right?

Comment: @David Sorry, I don't understand what you are saying?

Comment: sorry, i did what you said but i have to pass the parameter as reference because will change inside, or as out parameter, doing that, the compiler give me an error don't allow to put ref or out in the parameter in that object

Comment: @David You don't need to pass it by `ref`.

Comment: what is the return type of this function?

Comment: @sixfeet It's `void`, fixed it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I passed the ModelState to an IDisposable thinking that I would need to "free" the object when I was done with it, but just setted  it as readonly and still the errors were added to the "original" ModelState.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. What you're referencing inside Controller is its *property*, not a class. You can still pass it to the method being called as an argument.

Comment: I added the error inside string and i will get the message in controller, after it if message is empty no error otherwise i will add using AddModelError inside controller.

Answer (score 1):

Works well in ASP.NET Core 2 :

```
//Controller
if (MyValidator.SaveValidation(model, ModelState))
        {
            myManager.Update(model);

            return Json(new
            {
                responseText = "Saved"
            });
        }

//Validator
public static class SaveDossierValidator
{
    public static bool SaveValidation(MyModel model, ModelStateDictionary modelState)
    {
        if (model.property == null) {
            modelState.AddModelError("property", "Error message");
        }

        return modelState.IsValid;
    }
}
```