# Moq: Mocking Implementation of IValidatableObject?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, tdd

Let's say that I have a method that wishes to extract the ValidationResults from a concrete instance of an IValidatableObject and stick them somewhere else...say, from a DTO to a controller's ModelState.

How do I go about mocking the object that implements IValidatableObject?

Say, I had some code like this (doesn't yet compile):

```
[Test]
public void GivenBadObjectMethodShouldTransferErrorsToModelstate()
{
  // Mock BadObject and controller
  var controller = new Controller(); 
  var badObject = new Mock<ObjectImplementingIValidatableObject>();
  badObject.Setup( x => x.Validate(It.IsAny<ValidationContext>() )
           .Returns( new List<ValidationResult> { new ValidationResult("error") });

  // Invoke the method
  controller.TransferErrorsToModelStateFrom(badObject);

  // Check that ModelState contains the errors expected
  Assert.IsTrue(controller.ModelState.ContainsKeys("error") );
}
```

One issue I run into is with ValidationContext, getting errors like below:
System.NotSupportedException: Invalid setup on a non-virtual member x => x.Validate(It.IsAny())

Can you provide some insight on how to better approach this problem?

Thanks,

Chris

Answer (score 1):

You're mocking the ObjectImplementingIValidatableObject **concrete type**. This is probably not an interface and its Validate method is declared **non-virtual**. This is **a situation most isolation frameworks like Moq cannot handle**, as they work by dynamically generating subclasses (or implementations) of the mocked types at runtime.

If you provide an interface to be mocked, the isolation framework generates a fake implementation at runtime. If you provide a concrete type, the methods you stub/mock must be virtual in order for the framework to override them in the dynamically created subclass.

So in order for your snippet to work, consider working against an interface (perhaps just IValidatableObject) or making the Validate method declared on ObjectImplementingIValidatableObject virtual.

Comment: Thank you! I cannot believe I lost sight of programming to interfaces, here. The function already expects an IValidatableObject...so, I swapped it out, and it works great. See my answer for the final code.

Answer (score 0):

Easy to lose sight of programming to interfaces when swimming in all these things. Thanks for your help!

This is the code I ended up with: (I've included everything, though there are parts I could pull out into a setup method)

```
[Test]
    public void GivenValidatableObjectWithMemberErrorThenMethodShouldTransferMemberErrorToModelstate()
    {
        // Setup, getting protected member of abstract class instance
        var controller = (TestConcreteController)FormatterServices
            .GetUninitializedObject(typeof(TestConcreteController));

        MethodInfo ApplyErrorsToModelStateFromModel = controller
            .GetType()
            .GetMethod("ApplyErrorsToModelStateFromModel",
            BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

        // Setup, building expected objects to pass into method
        IEnumerable<ValidationResult> errors = new List<ValidationResult> 
        { 
            new ValidationResult(TestConstant.ExpectedErrorMessage, TestConstant.ExpectedMembers)
        };

        var objectWithMemberError = new Mock<IValidatableObject>();
        objectWithMemberError.Setup(x => x.Validate(It.IsAny<ValidationContext>()))
                             .Returns(errors);

        // Call the method
        ApplyErrorsToModelStateFromModel.Invoke(controller, new[] { objectWithMemberError.Object });

        // Check that member was added to list and contains the expected error
        Assert.IsTrue(controller.ModelState[TestConstant.ExpectedMembers[0]].Errors[0].ErrorMessage == TestConstant.ExpectedErrorMessage);
    }
```

Comment: Totally unrelated to your question but when you feel these kinds of pains when testing a piece of code, chances are the design of that piece could be improved (which both your testing and production code will benefit from). For example: why are you reaching into a protected member of an abstract class in your test? Perhaps that's your test telling you that the controller types have too many responsibilities and some kind of "validator" objects are dying to get out? This would make testing validation much easier and would allow you to plug in a fake validator obj when testing your controllers.

Comment: Thanks for your comments! I do already have a separate specification that tests the individual pieces of validation. What I'm trying to do is ensure those errors are being collected and presented to the user (I have a business object that is translated to a viewmodel and vice-versa). Can you please provide a concrete example?

Comment: Nevermind, I incorrectly understood that objects being passed by value by default meant I couldn't alter the object. Modelstate is a reference type, so the address is what is passed by value--so, I can dereference and call its methods and change Modelstate remotely! [This thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24081142/mvc-can-i-use-modelstate-inside-class-out-of-controller) finally helped me see the light of day...